# Specific json formatting return from Laravel Eloquent model

Tags: php, json, laravel-4

I am trying to format some data for Tags contained in a Laravel 4 model Tag:

```
id - integer
tag - string
```

simple stuff.
I have a route set up:

```
Route::get('data/tags', function() {
    $tags = Tag::all();
    return $tags;
}
```

So this returns json in the following format:

```
[{"id":"1","tag":"tag1"},{"id":"2","tag":"tag2"}]
```

The problem is, I am trying to make my json work with the `Twitter typeahead.js` library and, according to the docs there, it needs to look like:

```
{
  value: '@JakeHarding',
  tokens: ['Jake', 'Harding']
}
```

using my data, I believe that would mean (but I may be wrong here):

```
{
  value: '@tags',
  tokens: ['tag1', 'tag2']
}
```

So my query is, how do I make the output json from Laravel 4 match the json format needed by typeahead.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just loop the $tags and create a new array with the info on the format you need. Then just return this new array (Laravel will handle the conversion to json)